# Run nightwatchjs tests on real iOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, nightwatch.js

My nightwatch tests are already running on PC. I want to run them on real device both iOS and Android.

I have added following changes in my `nightwatch.json` file :

```
"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "https://www.google.com",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "on_error" : false,
        "path" : "./screenshot"
      },
      "log_screenshot_data": false,
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      },
      "globals": {
        "windowWidth" : "1400",
        "windowHeight" : "1050"
      },
      "exclude": ["TEMPLATE.js"]
    },
    "android" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",
      "selenium_port"  : 4723,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "platformName": "ANDROID",
        "deviceName": "R32D202V6MX"
      }
    },
    "ios" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "Safari",
        "platformName": "iOS",
        "platformVersion": "9.2",
        "deviceName": ""
      }
    },
```

How do I call `android` settings `test_settings` were getting fetched automatically when I run tests on PC.

I use following command to run tests:

`node nightwatch.js -t tests/firstTest.js` how to run same test on android?

Few more info:

1. Appium is running on 127.0.0.1:4723. http://127.0.0.1:4723/ gives "That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource"
2. Device is Samsung Nexus 10" tab v 4.4
3. PC is Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

To run nightwatch over iOS and android you must install:

1. Android Studio
2. Xcode (You have to be working on a Mac device for this step to work)
3. Appium + Appium-doctor

If you haven't set up these please follow the following link that provides excellent documentation on the issue :

> http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/2016/08/26/Mobile-Web-Testing-Using-Nightwatchjs-part-1/

If you have that part figured out. You can make nightwatch take the configuration you have set up by adding the following parameter:

> --env Desired_Environment

For instance, in your case it would be (for android):

> nightwatch -t tests/firstTest.js --env android

for multiple environments (running in parallel):

> nightwatch -t tests/firstTest.js --env android,ios

**Also make sure you specify the path to your nightwatch (Probably bin/nightwatch)**